# Aruba VPN configuration for Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I need to configure VPN client for Aruba Intranet Access.
Aruba provides VPN clients only for Windows, Mac and Android not for Linux.
May be someone can help me to configure Linux server?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Linux client available for download. Log in at support.arubanetworks.com and visit Downloads > VIA.